# What's the easiest way to play with Material Examples?

Tags: cosmicmind

I cloned the repro and opened the Material xcode worspace. What is the best way to play with the Examples? When I pick one of the examples under Programmatic, e.g. MaterialLayout I get runtime errors:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/robcecil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Material-gtachugnpsgijdekhozchyiudycc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Material.framework/Material
  Reason: image not found
```

In other cases, it has a hard time finding the Material framework...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To setup the example projects, you would need to compile the Material.framework, and then embed the framework in the project you want to run.

1. Open the Material workspace in the Examples directory.
2. Compile the Material.framework project by choosing the scheme in the Xcode navigation bar. The device needs to be on Generic Device, or an actual iOS device, not simulator.
3. Click on the project you want to run in the examples directory.
4. Open the 'General' page in the project inspector.
5. Go to Embedded Binaries, and add the Material.framework binary.
6. Choose the project scheme in the top navigation bar that you want to run.
7. Press run.

Check the [Installation](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/wiki/Installation) wiki page.