# Material examples crashing on launch

Tags: swift, cosmicmind

I'm trying to test the provided examples of the [Material](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material) library but all examples keep crashing with the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
  Referenced from: ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Material-fdsf..ef/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Material.framework/Material
  Reason: image not found
```

Not sure what is wrong there or if it is related to the actual examples or my setup.

Comment: For the love of design jesus, dont do this. Thats just horrible for your users. I hope apple rejects your app if you submit this.

Comment: Oscar, your comment seems a bit unrelated as I never mentioned an app or shared any code. Can you clarify your comment in a more helpful way.

Comment: Using Material design on iOS is a really bad idea, as the UI of your app should fit into the general theme of iOS. Apple has a page about this somewhere. iOS users are used to iOS design, making Android design un intuitive. Personally I think the whole Material design is bad even on Android, but at least keep iOS Apps out of it. My point is: Screw the library, design your app properly.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'm not planing to use Material design in my app. I'm just testing the library as it has a nice implementation of some UI elements with nice shadows and animations implemented. If I decide to use it, I would eliminate the things that makes it look Material.

Comment: @xemacobra Don't worry, Apple won't reject an app because they don't agree with the design style.  Personally I like material design and use it for iOS apps.

Comment: Checkout this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179233/whats-the-easiest-way-to-play-with-material-examples/35184508#35184508) seems like the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try cleaning your build directory and your Derived Data directory.

Similar issue and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179233/whats-the-easiest-way-to-play-with-material-examples/35184508#35184508)

Comment: The answer you linked worked. The problem was that I did not add the embedded library. That being said though, I think this process of building and running can be made easier and faster. Hopefully, it will get so with time. Thanks.